# rspec factory girl pass association to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Given these Rails models:

```
class Human
  has_many :pets
  has_many :vet_visits
end
class Pet
  belongs_to :human 
  has_many :vet_visits
end
class VetVisit
  belongs_to :human
  belongs_to :pet
end
```

I need an rspec factory to make a VetVisit. But:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :vet_visit, class: 'VetVisit' do 
    association :human, factory: :human
    association :pet, factory: :pet
  end
  factory :pet, class: 'Pet' do 
    association :human, factory: :human
  end
  factory :human, class: 'Human' do 
    after(:create) do | human |
      create :pet, human: human
    end
  end
end
```

results in a vet_visit with a human and a pet which are not each other's respective pet/human.

How do I make a factory which creates a vet_visit which has a pet with a human which is the same human as referenced by the vet_visit?

*To clear any doubt, I am not in fact making a vetinary system, this is an abstract example from a more complex system, removing the human and doing vet_visit.pet.human in the code is not suitable*

Answer (score 2):

If you need a vet visit that refers to a specific pet and human then build it within your spec file.

`let(:vet_visit) { FactoryGirl.create(:vet_visit, human: human, pet: pet) }`

This presumes you've already created a human and pet within your spec file.

Comment: Indeed, in many cases it makes sense to do it this way. But in more complex examples, this can mean defining hundreds of lets and passing them around. You could then, insist on importing YAML structures instead, but in the interest of having complete self contained factories, I am looking if there is a way to do it in FactoryGirl

Comment: one might wonder why you needed 100's of lets within a test.  If your test needs that many lets perhaps your tests need to be refactored then.  How is your test concept different if you have say 6 lets versus the 100.  If you need 'hundreds' of lets than you can most likely write a loop to do such things but I don't understands why one spec file would need 100s of variables defined like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `inverse_of` relationships in order for this to work.

When you create a human, a pet is created. That pet belongs to the human, but the human doesn't know about the pet.

Have a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations